# ".toFixed(1);" doesn't work for my each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="result">
  <div class="score">3.55</div>
  <div class="score">4.50</div>
  <div class="score">4.50</div>
  <div class="score">4.20</div>
  <div class="score">4</div>
</div>

<div class="result">
  <div class="score"5>2.33</div>
</div>
```

With jquery I count all "score divs", for each "result div" and create for each "result div" a new div with the result of it, called "goal".

My function:

```
$('.result').each(function () {
            var sum = 0;

            $(this).find('.score').each(function () {
                sum += Number($(this).text() / 5);
            });

            $(this).append('<div class="goal">' + sum + '</div>');
        });
```

**My problem**
I want to show only one number after the comma. I try to integrate ".toFixed(1);", but it always fails.

Something like this:

```
sum += (Number($(this).text() / 5)).toFixed(1);
```

The result of this try is an endless, wrong number ...

How will it work?

Comment: You need to convert `$(this).text()` to a Number : `+$(this).text()`

Comment: @Zenoo No, the `/5` casts to number just fine. In fact that whole `Number(...)` thing is unneeded since dividing by 5 already gives a number.

Comment: *"My example fiddle"* Please use Stack Snippets, not offsite fiddles. You do a Stack Snippets using the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string. You don't want to do string concatenation with the `+=` operator. Use `'<div class="goal">' + sum.toFixed(1) + '</div>'` in the end only

Comment: *"I try to integrate ".toFixed(1);", but it always fails."* [Fails **how**?](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)? Show us that attempt, so we can help you understand why it failed.

Comment: `sum += (Number($(this).text() / 5).toFixed(1));`

Comment: Thx guys for your really fast support - you are absolutly right!

Comment: While the only real option is to do this at time of output (as in the accepted answer) you can do this earlier if desired:  `Number( ($(this).text() / 5).toFixed(1) )`.  As already confirmed, `/5` gives a number so use `toFixed` on that number, but that gives you a string, so *wrap the toFixed* in `Number()`  (if so desired).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `/ 5` already casts to a number, you don't need `Number(...)` around that part at all. Just `sum += $(this).text() / 5;` will do. Unless you're pedantic, in which case `sum += parseFloat($(this).text()) / 5;` is what you need.

That aside, you should always work on "exact" numbers, and only apply rounding at the very end. So `'<div class="goal">' + sum.toFixed(1) + '</div>';`

Comment: Works perfect - thank you!! Also for the explantation - makes sense!